# How can I config my TP-LINK TD-8901G router to allow more than 8 MAC address filters using only a software?

Tags: windows-7, mac, router

My [TP-LINK TD-8901G](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TD-W8901G) router allows/disallows only 8 Wireless MAC address filters and I have more that 8 devices need to be access through it. So how to allow more that 8 devices on my router using only a software. I am using Windows 7 64 bit Ultimate edition.

Comment: Not to sidestep the issue, by why even worry about jumping through hoops for such an ineffective security measure?

Comment: sorry I couldn't get your point

Comment: If your router doesn't support it, why bother? MAC Filtering adds nearly zero security against those you really have anything to worry about with.

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: A secure passkey, and maybe enabling logging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [TP-LINK TD-W8901G](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TD-W8901G) does not provide the MAC filtering functionality you desire—and flashing it with alternative firmware like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) or [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org) is not supported—the best alternative you have is to get another router that has the MAC filtering functionality you desire and use the TP-LINK TD-W8901G in bridge mode.

Checking [the official documentation for the TP-LINK TD-W8901G](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/software/201161016042811.pdf) shows that it thankfully does support bridge mode:

> If you select this type of connection, the modem can be configured to
>   act as a bridging device between your LAN and your ISP. Bridges are
>   devices that enable two or more networks to communicate as if they are
>   two segments of the same physical LAN.

What bridge mode essentially means is this: Your TP-LINK TD-W8901G is a combination ADSL modem and router, but in bridge mode it will act only as an ADSL modem without using the router functionality. So that allows you to place a newer/better router that supports the functionality you seek between the TP-LINK TD-W8901G and your LAN.

And if you can purchase a nice router which is readily supported by alternative firmware packages DD-WRT or OpenWRT, that might be a better long term solution. Not only is the custom firmware DD-WRT or OpenWRT provides more robust and customizable, if you ever have issues or desire a new feature you could just contact the development team at either firmware project to see if they can help you.

Chances are there will not only be someone—a user or a developer—who can help you out much quicker than “official” OEM manufacturer support teams would, but perhaps your idea for a feature or improvement would be integrated into a future revision of their firmware.

Answer (score 0):

You could try fiddling around with third party firmware although based on what I’ve seen at the TP-Link TD-8901G doesn’t support at least one of the major third party firmware options, DD-WRT. [This thread](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=551668) indicates that router cannot use DD-WRT and [here is a list](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Known_incompatible_devices#General_Incompatibility_Information) of DD-WRT incompatible routers.

That said, here is info on [“How-to Setup a secure Wireless Network, DD-WRT.”](http://www.tomschaefer.org/how-to-setup-a-secure-wireless-network-dd-wrt/)

Ultimately, this means that you can bypass the standard 8 address issue by changing firmware/software on your router. But only if the router you are using supports using DD-WRT

Or you can attempt the following:

- You could try going after the company’s customer service in order to achieve support for what you want.
- You could try going after third party firmware manufacturers to achieve compatibility with your device.
- You could try purchasing a new router which is DD-WRT compatible or else has a better firmware which supports such functionality.
- You could try not using the filter? Surely, it allows access without a filter?
- You could try using an intermediate device which makes it look as though it is only accessing via a single MAC address though this isn’t much better than purchasing a new router in my opinion.